# Call method from another class in a new class - PHP

Tags: php, oop

I'm learning OOP PHP. I want to call a method from another class to a new class.

For just a example:

```
<?php 
class Aclass {
function aMethod($input)
     { 
       echo 'Hello a world '; 
     } 
} 
?>
```

And i want to call the method aMethod from the class '**Aclass**' into the new class.

```
<?php 
class Bclass {
//calling the method here?
} 
?>
```

i tried extending , still not working for me.

Thanks.

Comment: `i tried extending , still not working for me.` <-- perhaps show us your attempt?

Comment: Did my solution work for you?

Comment: Yes your solution worked for me bro @KarolGasienica ..

Comment: I'm glad I could help ;) Accept then an answer which helped you most :)

Comment: Glad I could help as well, and thanks for accepting my answer. :) Good luck forward!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this I'd use dependency injection. Which is just a fancy way of saying "sending an object of the `A` class when creating `B`".

In other words, something like this:

```
class typeA {
    public function __construct () {};
    public function test () {
        return 'Test string';
    }
}

class typeB {
    protected $testObj;

    public function __construct (typeA $testCase)  {
        $this->testObj = $testCase;
    }

    public function getTest () {
        return $this->testObj->test ();
    }
}

$a = new typeA ();
$b = new typeB ($a);
echo $b->getTest ();
```

Constructors are meant to be used to create an object that's *ready* to *be* used, which is why I've just stored the dependency inside the `typeB` object itself. Then, in the `getTest()` method I invoke the `test()` method of the object I'm depending upon, in order to get the needed data from it.
Doing it in this manner will allow you to write flexible OOP code, which can easily be expanded and extended as you require. Hiding the dependencies inside the constructors, by creating objects there, creates a hidden and hard dependency. Something which makes it a lot harder, if not down right impossible, to properly leverage the extensible nature of the class-based designs.

Comment: That might be hard for beginner :D and if he will use some `Aclass` methods in only a few situations in `Bclass`, why should he always create a new instance at the beginning?

Comment: @KarolGasienica I don't agree that this would be hard for a beginner, as this is as basic OOP as you get. Without proper dependency injection things _will_ get a lot harder in the long run, and cause headaches when something needs to be changed (which it will). Better to get into the habit of good OOP to start with. As for the aside: If you have a class of only a couple methods, with no internal state, used in only one other class: Re-examine the need for making it a class in the first place.

Answer (score 2):

In your class `Bclass` you should create some functions. In case below you are creating a new instance of `Aclass` and then using function `aMethod`.

**Example**

```
<?php 
class Bclass {       
    public function __construct() {
        $a = new Aclass();
        $a->aMethod("some_text");
    }
} 
?>
```

Other way is extend `Bclass`. In this case your class `Bclass` extends everything what's in `Aclass` so you can use it just with `$this`.

**Example**

```
<?php 
class Bclass extends Aclass {
    public function __construct() {
        $this->aMethod("some_text");
    }
} 
?>
```

Also your function `aMethod` in `Aclass` should have public or protected visibility. Public if you create an instance, protected if you extends. More informations can be found in manuals at the end.

**Example**

```
<?php 
class Aclass {
public function aMethod($input) // protected if you will extend this class
     { 
       echo 'Hello a world '; 
     } 
} 
?>
```

You can of course use both methods not only in `__construct` but also in other functions.

**Manuals**

[PHP: Visibility](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.visibility.php)

[PHP: Constructors and Destructors](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.decon.php)

Comment: for the first case it must be public for the second case it can be either public or protected

Comment: there is no need for the `print_r`, the function already echos. And maybe you should mention that `$this->aMethod` can be used anywhere in the `class` not just in the constructor.

Comment: Quick comment: Using `echo` and similar functions/language constructs inside a class is considered bad form. Classes should be atomic, and self-contained. Any side-effects on external systems should be handled by the controlling code, and output sent to a view/template by said controlling code. Locking the class in this manner makes it _less_ flexible, and as such goes against the OOP principles.

Comment: You are totally right, `__construct` is not for that. It is just example. He even should use It in other functions. I just think inside `aMethod` will be something else than `echo`.

Comment: You can accept only one answer by the way :D Your welcome ;)